# Django: HTTP error 410 (Gone) with RedirectView

Tags: python, django, web-services, web

I get an HTTP 410 error when invoking the following Django View:

```
>>> views.py:

class ReopenMilestoneView(
    dj_auth_mixins.LoginRequiredMixin, dj_views.RedirectView
):

    pattern_name = 'bibliotheka_dashboard'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print('DISPATCH BEGIN')
        instance = project_models.Milestone.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        instance.state = project_models.STATE_OPEN
        instance.save()
        print('DISPATCH END')

        return super(ReopenMilestoneView, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs
        )


    def http_method_not_allowed(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('HTTP NOT ALLOWED BEGIN')
        try:
            return super(ReopenMilestoneView, self).http_method_not_allowed(
                *args, **kwargs
            )
        except:
            print('EXCEPTION')
        print('HTTP NOT ALLOWED END')

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('REDIRECT BEGIN')
        result = super(ReopenMilestoneView, self).get_redirect_url(
            *args, **kwargs
        )
        print('REDIRECT END, result = ' + str(result))
        url = urlresolvers.reverse('bibliotheka_dashboard')
        url2 = urlresolvers.reverse(self.pattern_name)
        print('REDIRECT END, URL_resolved = ' + str(url))
        print('REDIRECT END, pattern_name = ' + str(self.pattern_name))
        print('REDIRECT END, URL_2_resolved = ' + str(url2))

        return result

>>> urls.py:

...
    url(
        r'^milestone/dashboard/$',
        project_views.MilestoneDashboard.as_view(),
        name='milestone_dashboard'
    ),
    url(
        r'^milestone/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/dashboard/$',
        project_views.MilestoneDashboard.as_view(),
        name='milestone_specific_dashboard'
    ),
...
```

I added prints through the three methods form "RedirectView" that are mentioned in the Django documentation as part of the regular workflow ([django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)).

Dispatch is properly executed but, when resolving automatically the "pattern_name", "RedirectView" fails... manually resolving it, solves the problem.

```
DISPATCH BEGIN
DISPATCH END
REDIRECT BEGIN
REDIRECT END, result = None
REDIRECT END, URL_resolved = /
REDIRECT END, pattern_name = bibliotheka_dashboard
REDIRECT END, URL_2_resolved = /

Gone: /prj/milestone/2/reopen/
[12/Jul/2017 13:28:34] "GET /prj/milestone/2/reopen/ HTTP/1.1" 410 0
```

I have used "RedirectView" before but I have never got this error, any ideas? Django is not returning a lot of info back...

My URLs are defined as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls import static as dj_static
from django.contrib import admin

from bibliotheka import settings as bibliotheka_settings
from documentation.views import project as project_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(
        r'^$',
        project_views.MilestoneDashboard.as_view(),
        name='bibliotheka_dashboard'
    ),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^prj/', include('documentation.urls.project')),
    url(r'^dox/', include('documentation.urls.documents')),
    url(r'^dox/', include('documentation.urls.discrepancies')),
]

if bibliotheka_settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += dj_static.static(
        bibliotheka_settings.MEDIA_URL,
        document_root=bibliotheka_settings.MEDIA_ROOT
    )
```

I am trying to redirect to "/" with the problematic views.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django is failing to reverse `milestone_dashboard`. In Django <= 1.11, it silences the `NoReverseMatch`, and returns a 410 response.

This behaviour has been changed in [Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/#miscellaneous) (see [ticket 26911](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.0/#miscellaneous)), so Django will no longer silence the exception.

When you use [`pattern_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.pattern_name), Django tries to reverse with the same args and kwargs. You do not want this, as you are redirecting from a url containing the `pk` to a url that does not have any arguments.

You can set `url` with `reverse_lazy`:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class ReopenMilestoneView(RedirectView):
    url = reverse_lazy('bibliotheka_dashboard')
```

Comment: I have checked the Django version that I am using and is Django 1.11.1, should'nt that exception be thrown in that version (>1.11)?

Comment: When I said <= 1.11 I meant <= 1.11.x. The change was made in the master branch (which will become Django 2.0) . It has not been backported, so is not in Django 1.11.x.

Comment: When I add the app tag with the semicolon, I get the following warning from Django: "?: (urls.W003) Your URL pattern '^issue/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/author/reopen/' [name='documentation:issue_author_reopen'] has a name including a ':'. Remove the colon, to avoid ambiguous namespace references." What do you think?

Comment: That seems like a completely unrelated issue. Your question doesn't mention `issue_author_reopen` anywhere. Did you try removing the colon, as the message suggests?

Comment: You are right: that new comment does not relate to the original one. I was just mentioning the output message from Django when adding the label with the semicolon. I did removed the semicolon, I just wanted to know if that was a not recommended practice by Django.

Comment: No problem, that's something that I already understood. Please take a look at the update of the issue.

Comment: Your updates don't really add anything to the question -- I still think the problem is that Django is failing to reverse the URL. If you can't fix that, then you need to show your full urls.py, and show how you include your urls.

Comment: As you can see in the last test case, for some reason, RedirectView is not properly resolving the URL using the given "pattern_name". If I do it manually, the URL is resolved properly. What might I be missing?

Comment: OK, I see the problem now. You shouldn't be using `pattern_name`. You can set `url` instead.

Comment: Ok... however, in accordance with the documentation, "pattern_name" can be used that way... right? As per Django's official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Comment: You're not reading the docs you linked to: *reversing will be done using the same args and kwargs as are passed in for this view.* You tried `reverse(self.pattern_name)` when you were debugging, but Django actually runs `reverse(self.pattern_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)`.

Comment: I can't see exactly how "*args" and "**kwargs" can affect resolving an URL pattern when the pattern has no arguments itself. Moreover, if you take a look at the example provided, I can't tell what I can be doing wrong.

Comment: Inside the `get_redirect_url` method, `kwargs` is `{'pk': '2'}`. Django tries to do `reverse('bibliotheka_settings', kwargs={'pk': '2'})`. This fails, because you do not have a url pattern named `'bibliotheka_settings'` with a group named `pk`.

Comment: I think that I would've never figured that out by myself... thanks!